# want to stop users entering invalid email addresses into form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to be able to run a php validate script to stop users form entering gibberish as their email address. I know we can have the form input type as email but that can be easily bypassed in developer tools and the database integrity damaged.

My insert page looks like this:

```
$email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['emailpost']);
        $password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['passpost']);
        $firstname = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['firstnamepost']);
        $lastname = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['lastnamepost']);
        $phonenumber = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['phonenumberpost']);
        $education = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['institutionpost']);
        $facebook = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['facebookpost']);
        $twitter = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['twitterpost']);
        $instagram = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['instagrampost']);

        $filename = $_FILES['uploadprofileimg']['name'];
        $filename = $ran.$filename;
        $filetmp = $_FILES['uploadprofileimg']['tmp_name'];
        $filetype = $_FILES['uploadprofileimg']['type'];
        move_uploaded_file($filetmp, "../userimages/".$filename);

    $insertuser = "INSERT INTO elmtree_users (user, email, pw, firstName, lastName, profileimg, learninginstitute, phone, facebook, twitter, instagram) VALUES
    ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$filename', '$education', '$phonenumber', '$facebook', '$twitter', '$instagram')";



        $resultinsert = $conn -> query($insertuser);

        if(!$resultinsert){

        echo $conn->error;
        }else{

        echo "<h2> Account successfully registered!</h2> 
                <h4>Please <a href='login.php'> <font class='text-success'><strong>login.</strong></font></a></h4><br><br><br><br>";
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Force email verification. This is the only way to reliably validate an email address. People are going to enter junk, and if you make them enter valid-looking junk, be prepared to clean your database. There's no way around this step.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Send an email to the given address and include a link in it with some secret, randomly generated token. When that link is visited, flag the account as confirmed.

Comment: Your file upload is also dangerous. You should do some sort of checking of the file, or renaming before just putting it on the file system.

Comment: Im a beginner please write the line of code for me so I can see it

Comment: look this link i hope it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460896/check-username-and-email-already-exists-in-php-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone is pointing out

making your own logging system is tricky. it required you to do additional steps to make the content secured. Not only to hackers but you as administrator of the database shouldn't have access to see your customers password in `PlainText` Most users will use the same password on your site as they used for there email password they registered with on your site..

It is more advisable to create login tools like laravel, Or simply research how to build a secure login system, because what we are seeing here in your code, is BAD, Not syntactically, but from a security stand point.

Me knowing you store passwords like that, I wouldn't register onto your website.

Any how not only that, But you really should have a look into `mysqli` `binding`
Or even, and something I like better is `PDO_Mysql`
Your code will not only be more clear to read, but will bind values directly to a a field within mysql  ( no need to use `real_escape_string` no more )

Now to actually answer your question.

You probably should make some kind of `javascript` live validator on the field of your form directly.

then on PHP side, You can do a simple condition with `REGXP` and `preg_match()`

Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/SOgUIV/1 this is a regex that will validate EMAILs.
With this link, You should then experiment a bit with it, it has not only documentation on the side but also possibles quantifier and such.

```
if(preg_match("/^((?!\.)[\w-_.]*[^.])(@\w+)(\.\w+(\.\w+)?[^.\W])$/i",trim($_POST['Email']))){
//What ever is in here will get process when $_POST['emailpost'] is valid.
}
```

Edited ----

As some user pointed out in comments.
You would probably be better of using

```
if(filter_var($_POST['emailpost'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL){
  //What ever is in here will get process when $_POST['emailpost'] is valid
}
```

Also if you want to make sure user has access to the email address account, You could also add two column within your `users` table, `isConfirmed`,`ConfirmationCode`

When the user register, You create a `unique` code and put it into `ConfirmationCode` then send the user an email with something along those line "Please click the following link to activate account www.yourWebSite.com/confirmationPage.php?Code=$TheActualCodeYouCreatedForThatUser"
Then once user get to that page, Change the field `isConfirmed` to '1' or true.

Once there on your website, you will be able to assume that only emails with `isConfirmed` is a real user.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php Should be used over a regex. Neither of these solutions would stop `entering gibberish` though. Verifying with a random string sent to the inbox is the only real solution.

Comment: Instead or regex, I suggest using [`filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) Example: https://3v4l.org/bZ8se Your current regex fails to match some [RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part) compliant names and domains.

Comment: Would be nice if you put some code to explain some of this things to him. He is a newbie

Answer (score -1):

To validate email you need to check a lot of stuff like

1. if the email already exists
2. if its a real email i.e check for presence of @
3. check for funny characters which are not supposed to be in an email.

then always encrypt your password

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $errors = array();

    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['emailpost']);
    $password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['passpost']);
    $firstname = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['firstnamepost']);
    $lastname = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['lastnamepost']);
    $phonenumber = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['phonenumberpost']);
    $education = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['institutionpost']);
    $facebook = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['facebookpost']);
    $twitter = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['twitterpost']);
    $instagram = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['instagrampost']);

    $filename = $_FILES['uploadprofileimg']['name'];
    $filename = $ran.$filename;
    $filetmp = $_FILES['uploadprofileimg']['tmp_name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['uploadprofileimg']['type'];
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp, "../userimages/".$filename);

    if (strlen($email) && strlen($password) && strlen($firstname) && strlen($lastname) && strlen($phonenumber) && strlen($education) && strlen($facebook) && strlen($twitter) && strlen($instagram)) {
        //check for a valid email
        if(preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$^",$email))
            $errors['email'] = 'invalid email address';

        //check for presence of @ in email
        if (!stristr($em,"@") OR !stristr($em,".") $errors['email'] = 'please enter an email';

        //echeck if email already exists in database
        $checkemail = $conn->get_row("SELECT * FROM elmtree_users WHERE email=".$email);
        if( $conn->num_rows( $checkemail ) > 0 ) $errors['email'] = "User already exists with the email: " . $email;

        //validate password
        $minpasslen = 8;
        if (strlen($password) < $minpasslen)
            $errors['email'] = 'password is too short';
        $finalpassword = MD5($password);
        if (empty($errors)) {
            $insertuser = "INSERT INTO elmtree_users (user, email, pw, firstName, lastName, profileimg, learninginstitute, phone, facebook, twitter, instagram) VALUES
            ('$username', '$email', '$finalpassword', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$filename', '$education', '$phonenumber', '$facebook', '$twitter', '$instagram')";

            $resultinsert = $conn -> query($insertuser);
            if(!$resultinsert){
                echo $conn->error;
            } else {
                echo "<h2> Account successfully registered!</h2> 
                        <h4>Please <a href='login.php'> <font class='text-success'><strong>login.</strong></font></a></h4><br><br><br><br>";

        } else {
            echo implode('<br>', $errors);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't encrypting the password here, that is hashing. `MD5` should no longer be used. Additionally `if (!stristr($em,"@") OR !stristr($em,".") $errors['email']` is a syntax error, is open to SQL injections, and `WHERE email=".$email` is not valid sql because `email` is a string.

Comment: `Why are you making a lot of noise`?? Why am I trying to help you and the OP? I don't know seems like I'm wasting my time again :(.